# C Programming (Program does not go out of loop)

Tags: c

This is the output of my program. Even though the conditions have been met, it still does not go out of the loop[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofjlF.jpg)

This is my program. The first while loop asks if the user owns a car.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define TRANSPORT 1


int main()
{
    char PrivateVehicle;

    printf("DRIVING ANF FLYING CARBON FOORPRINT \n");

    printf("I. LAND \n");

    printf("A. PRIVATE OWNED \n");

    while (TRANSPORT==1)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Question 1: \n");
            printf("Do you have your own private vehicle? [Y/y]-Yes, [N/n]-No \n");
            printf("Note: Only the letters Y, y for yes and N, n for no would be accepted \n");
            scanf (" %c", &PrivateVehicle);

            if (PrivateVehicle!='Y' && PrivateVehicle!='y' && PrivateVehicle!='N' && PrivateVehicle!='n')
                printf("Inavlid \n");
        } while (PrivateVehicle!='Y' && PrivateVehicle!='y' && PrivateVehicle!='N' && PrivateVehicle!='n');

        if (PrivateVehicle=='Y'|| PrivateVehicle=='y') // should go out of the loop after condition is met
            printf("Y/y\n"); //For checking

        else if (PrivateVehicle=='N'|| PrivateVehicle=='n') // should go out of the loop after condition is met
            printf("N/n\n"); //For checking

        TRANSPORT==0;

    }

    printf("Out"); //For checking

    printf("B. PUBLIC TRANSPORT \n");
}
```

Comment: This program does not seem to output an image. I did not check but if your 'output' is regular plain text, put it as such in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to a macro identifier with

```
 TRANSPORT == 0;
```

(even when "fixing" the `==` with `=`). You need to use a variable if you need to change a value of something, e.g. `int TRANSPORT = 0;` instead of the `#define` directive.

The reason for the non-terminating loop is that after macro expansion, you have

```
 while (1==1)
```

which is always true.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `TRANSPORT` is a preprocessor macro, it can't be changed at run-time. In fact, in the generated code there is no reference to the `TRANSPORT` symbol at all, it doesn't exist once the preprocessor *replaces* it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

TRANSPORT is define as preprocessor macro - you yould change it to be a variable. 
Then you'd still need to changehe evaulation`TRANSPORT==0;` to be an assignment `TRANSPORT=0;`

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't use `#define TRANSPORT 1`, but instead `int TRANSPORT = 1` or something like that.

> The #define creates a macro, which is the association of an identifier
>   or parameterized identifier with a token string. After the macro is
>   defined, the compiler can substitute the token string for each
>   occurrence of the identifier in the source file.